# DialogFragment orientation change

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, orientation-changes

I have an activty and two fragments. One of the fragments extends DialogFragment and shows some text.
In my activity i have overriden onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layoutId);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        initFragment();
}
```

initFragment() adds a fragment to a FrameLayout in my layoutId. If no DialogFragment is shown everything works fine, but in case DialogFragment instance is shown - orientation change throws IllegalStateException that fragment did not return View on the line "setContentView".

BTW I'm using ActionBarSherlock

```
E/AndroidRuntime(19517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{ru.nixan.android/ru.nixan.android.Cards}: android.view.InflateException: B
inary XML file line #30: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivi
ty(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActi
vity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(Activit
yThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
tivityThread.java:1151)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
11)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(19517): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML fi
le line #30: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(Layout
Inflater.java:606)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
(LayoutInflater.java:680)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutIn
flater.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutIn
flater.java:742)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInf
later.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInf
later.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInf
later.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.
generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2707)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.
installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2767)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.
setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:247)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherl
ockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentAct
ivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:309)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at ru.nixan.android.Cards.onCreate(Cards.java:53)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.j
ava:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCre
ate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        ... 12 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19517): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative
(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Con
structor.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(Layout
Inflater.java:586)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        ... 27 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19517): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML fi
le line #7: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
(LayoutInflater.java:697)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutIn
flater.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInf
later.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInf
later.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<in
it>(ActionBarView.java:236)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        ... 30 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19517): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ru
.nixan.android.fragments.BalanceFragment did not create a view.
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCre
ateView(FragmentActivity.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
(LayoutInflater.java:669)
E/AndroidRuntime(19517):        ... 34 more
W/ActivityManager(30340):   Force finishing activity ru.nixan.android/.Cards
```

ErrorDialog.java

```
public class ErrorDialog extends SherlockDialogFragment implements
        OnClickListener {

    public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "error";

    public static final String EXTRA_EXCEPTION = "exception";

    public static ErrorDialog getInstance(Exception excpetion) {
        ErrorDialog result = new ErrorDialog();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putSerializable(EXTRA_EXCEPTION, excpetion);
        result.setArguments(data);
        return result;
    }

    // some methods that are not in lifecycle are not presented here.

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setShowsDialog(true);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialogErrorTitle);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialogDismissButton, this);
        Exception exception = (Exception) getArguments().getSerializable(
                EXTRA_EXCEPTION);
        builder.setMessage(getErrorMessage(exception, getActivity()));
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cards);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        if (data == null || PATH_MENU.equals(data.getLastPathSegment()))
            initMenuFragment();
        else if (PATH_CARDS.equals(data.getLastPathSegment()))
            initCardsFragment();
    }
}

private void showError(Exception exception) {
    ErrorDialog.getInstance(exception).show(getSupportFragmentManager());

}
```

Comment: could you post the whole exception and more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same situation in my own implementation.
You can check out the workaround I came up with here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14774821/1894568

basically its about NOT using fragments in the layout-xml, because lifecycle is different from fragments added via FragmentManager. Instead inject the orientation-specific Fragments (LandscapeModeFragment & PortraitModeFragment) into a FrameLayout-container.