# Orientation Change: IllegalStateException when DialogFragment is visible

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-dialogfragment

I'd like to let Android handle orientation change. 
Unfortunately it crashes each time a dialog is open and orientation change occurs.
I already suspect the cause but don't know how to handle it:

When Application first starts backstack looks like this:

```
02-07 15:25:36.517: I/System.out(14541): Added Fragments:
02-07 15:25:36.517: I/System.out(14541):   #0: PortraitModeFragment{41963330 #0 id=0x7f090001 ListViewFragment}
```

great, now we open a dialog:

```
02-07 15:26:03.316: I/System.out(14541): Added Fragments:
02-07 15:26:03.316: I/System.out(14541):   #0: PortraitModeFragment{41963330 #0 id=0x7f090001 ListViewFragment}
02-07 15:26:03.326: I/System.out(14541):   #1: MyDialogFragment{4199f6a0 #1 MyDialogFragment}
```

And now when rotate the device:

```
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    ... 12 more
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.testapp.fragments.LandscapeModeFragment did not create a view.
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:303)
02-07 15:26:37.502: E/AndroidRuntime(14541):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

Interesting fun-fact: This does not happen if I first turn around the device and subsequently open the dialog and change orientation, because both fragments are preloaded and exist peacefully in the backstack:

```
02-07 15:34:00.015: I/System.out(15412):   #0: PortraitModeragment{419b99b0 #0 id=0x7f090001 ListViewFragment}
02-07 15:34:00.015: I/System.out(15412):   #1: LandscapeModeFragment{419b9b88 #1 id=0x7f090003 LandscapeModeFragment}
02-07 15:34:00.025: I/System.out(15412):   #2: MyDialogFragment{419d1da0 #2 MyDialogFragment}
```

I cant make the user rotate the smartphone around before using my app, so what to do? ;)

**To reproduce:**

How I add the Dialog to backstack:

```
MyDialogFragment myTvShowDialog = new MyDialogFragment();
myTvShowDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),myTvShowDialog.TAG);
```

What I did was create two xml files for MainActivity:

1 . res/layout/main.xml (PortraitMode):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:layout_width="match_parent"    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="layout-land/PORTRAIT" />
     <fragment class="com.example.testapp.fragments.PortraitModeFragment"
                        android:id="@+id/fragment" android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:tag="PortraitModeFragment">
     </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

2 . res/layout-land/main.xml (LandscapeMode)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:layout_width="match_parent"    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView   android:id="@+id/textView1"   android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:text="layout-land/LANDSCAPE" />
    <fragment class="com.example.testapp.fragments.LandscapeModeFragment"
            android:id="@+id/LandscapeModeFragment" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0dp" android:tag="LandscapeModeFragment">
     </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().dump("", null,
                new PrintWriter(System.out, true), null);
    }
}
```

FragmentPortraitMode:

```
public class PortraitModeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.portraitmodefragment_layout,
            null);
    Button findViewById = (Button) fragment.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    findViewById.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyDialogFragment myDialog = new MyDialogFragment();
            myDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    MyDialogFragment.TAG);
        }
    });
    TextView textView = (TextView) fragment.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(TAG);
    return fragment;
}
```

Fragment LandscapeMode:

```
public class LandscapeModeFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "LandscapeModeFragment";

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.landscapemode_fragment_layout,
            container, false);
    return fragment;
}
}
```

landscapemode_fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LANDSCAPEFRAGMENT" />
</LinearLayout>
```

portraitmode_fragment_layout_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button   android:id="@+id/button1"    android:layout_width="wrap_content"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is/where is 'generic_dialog_layout.xml' that fails to be inflated in LandscapeModeFragment?

Comment: @Kerry added the layout for the dialog, naming was weak here i admit. its just a generic layout...

Comment: I changed the naming of the used layout.xml to landscape_fragment_layout.xml now naming-wise it should be clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I've found a workaround which works just as fine.

**First: What was the problem?**

Fragments defined in the layout-xml and fragments added per FragmentManager have different lifecycles abd though it is possible to mess with the layout-fragments with the FragmentManager unexpected behaviour (Exceptions) causes the application to crash.

[As Dianne Hackborn mentioned in the Google Groups Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de&fromgroups=#!searchin/android-developers/fragment%2420layout%2420orientation/android-developers/tWln4PFHFo0/gopXeMasYCgJ)

> Defining fragments in XML is mostly intended for things that are going
>   to stay around.  If you are going to add and remove, you should
>   probably consistently do it dynamically.
>
> I can look into this for a future release, but please note that
>   whatever I do you can easily get yourself into bad situations using
>   this -- for example if you don't have a unique containing view group
>   for the fragment, what happens as you remove/add fragments at that
>   point in the hierarchy is going to behave inconsistently.

So we are not allowed to mix worlds (FragmentManager-Fragments and LayoutXML-Fragments). This unfortunately involves DialogFragments added at Runtime too. What happens: Android-Framework adds on orientation-change the newly layout-created Fragment into the backstack. The FragmentManager trys to add the DialogFragment afterwards on the same index as the newly created Layout-Fragment. Thats when things get messy and IllegalStateException occurs.

**So, whats the workaround?**

Most examples using Fragments for different orientations involve defining a FrameLayout as container, to put the correct Fragment into it. So we'll go all the way with the FragmentManager and bann the LayoutFragments from our design:

ActivityMain uses just this simple xml as its contentView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

and when started it injects correct Fragment into the container

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity_framelayout);
    createFragmentIfNotExits();
}
private void createFragmentIfNotExits() {
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    Fragment newFragment;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        newFragment = new TvShowListPortraitModeFragment();
    } else {
        newFragment = new TvShowListLandscapeModeFragment();
    }
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container_id, newFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

**The Drawback:** 
Unfortunately retaining the saved state of fragments is not possible this way. Or at least I still need to figure our how to do this.

So much from me. I will not mark this answer as "answered" since I did not really make it work, maybe someone will figure it out and post a simpler solution. I will mark this then ofcourse as correct.

Comment: because the guyes and girls from android dev team do not bother with fixing bugs, rather introduce new versions with new bugs, i dont think there will ever be a better solution of the official bug you described http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18529

Comment: I found useful the alternative workaround described in the bug at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18529#c8